# Using a block variable to stop multiple events running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery slider that will cycle through images from to left to right.
There are also buttons on the left and right hand side of the slider that will allow the user to scroll through the images manually if they want to.

The problem I'm having is that if these buttons are clicked multiple times the images will slide off the page, this is because the events are fired before the left property of the list is beyond its boundary.

I am trying to use a variable to block the user being able to fire these events by checking if a current animation  is already taking place, but the events still seem to fire. Here  is a  working jsFiddle that shows the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/25tt5vmp/10/

Here is the jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var myTimer = setInterval(slide, 2000);
    var blockedSlider = false;

    function slide() {
            var left = $('#sliderList').css('left');
            left = left.substring(0, left.length - 2);
            if (left <= -800) {


                $('#sliderList').css('left', '-400px');
                var slide = $('#sliderList li:first');
                $('#sliderList').children('li:first').remove();
                $('#sliderList').append(slide);
                $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "-=400px" }, "slow", "swing");

            }
            else {
                $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "-=400" }, "slow", "swing");
            }

    }

    $('#sliderLeft').click(function () {
        if (blockedSlider == false) {
            blockedSlider = true;
            var left = $('#sliderList').css('left');
            left = left.substring(0, left.length - 2);
            if (left <= -800) {
                $('#sliderList').css('left', '-400px');
                var slide = $('#sliderList li:first');
                $('#sliderList').children('li:first').remove();
                $('#sliderList').append(slide);
                $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "-=400px" }, "slow", "swing");
                clearInterval(myTimer);
                myTimer = setInterval(slide, 2000);
            }
            else {
                $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "-=400" }, "slow", "swing");
                clearInterval(myTimer);
                myTimer = setInterval(slide, 2000);
            }
            blockedSlider = false;
        }
    });

    $('#sliderRight').click(function () {
        if (blockedSlider == false) {
            blockedSlider = true;
            var left = $('#sliderList').css('left');
            left = left.substring(0, left.length - 2);
            if (left >= 0) {
                $('#sliderList').css('left', '-400px');
                var slide = $('#sliderList li:last');
                $('#sliderList').children('li:last').remove();
                $('#sliderList').prepend(slide);
                $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "+=400px" }, "slow", "swing");
                clearInterval(myTimer);
                myTimer = setInterval(slide, 2000);

            }
            else {
                $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "+=400" }, "slow", "swing");
                clearInterval(myTimer);
                myTimer = setInterval(slide, 2000);
            }
            blockedSlider = false;
        }
    });

});
```

And my HTML:

```
<div  id="sliderOuterWrapper">
        <div id="sliderWrapper">

            <a id="sliderLeft"  ><</a>
            <a id="sliderRight" >></a>
            <ul id="sliderList">
                <li class="sliderItem first">
                    <div><img src="" /></div>
                </li>
                <li class="sliderItem second">
                    <div><img src="" /></div>
                </li>
                <li class="sliderItem third">
                    <div><img src="" /></div>
                </li>
                <li class="sliderItem fourth">
                    <div><img src="" /></div>
                </li>
                <li class="sliderItem fifth">
                    <div><img src="" /></div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#sliderWrapper { width: 400px; height: 350px; overflow: hidden; position:relative;}
#sliderList  { list-style: none; left: 0px; position:absolute; width:200000em;}
.sliderItem { float: left; background-color:black; width: 400px; height: 350px;}
.sliderItem.first { background-color:red; }
.sliderItem.second { background-color:blue; }
.sliderItem.third { background-color:yellow; }
.sliderItem.fourth { background-color:green; }
#sliderLeft  { position: absolute; font-size: 63px; top:39%; z-index: 10;}
#sliderRight { position: absolute; font-size: 63px; top:39%; z-index: 10; right: 0px;}
#sliderLeft:hover,
#sliderRight:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

How   can I stop these events from firing if a current animation is already taking place?

Comment: First thing you'll want to do is immediately `return` from you click handler if `blockedSlider` is true. Then in the callback of the animation, set it back to false so that subsequent clicks will trigger the animation again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set back blockSlider to false in teh animate function call back

```
 $('#sliderLeft').click(function () {
        if (blockedSlider == false) {
            blockedSlider = true;
            var left = $('#sliderList').css('left');
            left = left.substring(0, left.length - 2);
            if (left <= -800) {
                $('#sliderList').css('left', '-400px');
                var slide = $('#sliderList li:first');
                $('#sliderList').children('li:first').remove();
                $('#sliderList').append(slide);
                $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "-=400px" }, "slow", "swing",function(){
                    blockedSlider = false
                 });
                clearInterval(myTimer);
                myTimer = setInterval(slide, 2000);
            }
            else {
                $('#sliderList').animate({ left: "-=400" }, "slow", "swing",function(){
                    blockedSlider = false
                 });
                clearInterval(myTimer);
                myTimer = setInterval(slide, 2000);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: This works ! Only thing is, it then doesn't continue to slide after the user has manually scrolled ? http://jsfiddle.net/25tt5vmp/26/

Comment: you are reusing the variable "var slide" in the click handler. so in setInterval function it is referring the local variable instead of the global function